# Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

Как можно Dictionary вывести в виде?:

```
key1
   val1
   val2
   val3
key2
   val1
   val2
   val3
```

Comment: В `Dictionary` с одним ключом может быть связано только одно значение. Возможно вам нужен `Lookup`, ну или в качестве значения в словаре использовать список. Но скорее всего я не понял вопроса.

Comment: Возможно вам нужно посетить сайт с документацией? Не ужели в сети нет примеров кода вывода Dictionary ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сам Dictionary подразумевает хранение данных в виде Key=Value, где *один* `Key` содержит только *один* `Value`. Но, благо Value у нас может содержать почти любой объект, а это значит, что мы без труда можем добавлять туда коллекции.

Вот пример простейшего словаря с массивом:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    ["key1"] = new[]
    {
        "val1",
        "val2",
        "val3",
    },
    ["key2"] = new[]
    {
        "val1",
        "val2",
        "val3",
    },
};
```

Если надо добавить что то, то мы смело можем сделать следующее:

```
dictionary.Add("key3", new []{"val1", "val2"});
```

Изменение значений, самое простое:

```
dictionary["key2"][0] = "val11";
```

Ну и вывод того, что вы хотите:

```
foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}");
    foreach (var val in item.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   " + val);
    }
}
```

Ну или можем извратиться и сделать вывод через LINQ:

```
var result = dictionary.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
    (sb, kvp) => sb.AppendLine(kvp.Key).AppendLine(string.Join("\n", kvp.Value.Select(x => $"   {x}"))),
    builder => builder.ToString());

Console.Write(result);
```

Результат:

```
key1
   val1
   val2
   val3
key2
   val1
   val2
   val3
```

Comment: У меня есть Dictionary<int, List<Obj>>() .А если я сделаю ToDictionary(obj => obj.Property) для коллекции(Простой List<Obj>).. у меня будет Dictionary<int, List<Obj>>()?

Comment: просто в копилку ещё один способ `var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() { { "key1", new[] { "val1", "val2", "val3" } }, { "key2", new[] { "val1", "val2", "val3" } }, };`

Comment: @arstan Таким образом вы получите Dictionary, где ключ = Obj, а если в `List<Obj>` будет два одинаковых значения, то и вовсе получите ошибку. Лучше исходную коллекцию сначала сгруппировать, а уж затем переводить в Dictionary, но это уже другой вопрос...